# How to get key of dynamic created input fields in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have multiple input elements like:

```
<input type="text" name="attribute_name[attr_1]" placeholder="Attribute Name" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_name[attr_2]" placeholder="Attribute Name" class="form-control" required="">
..
..
```

Now i want to loop through all the input elements and i want to get array key also, i.e. attr_1 in this case :

i'm using the following code but it is not getting key:

```
foreach($request->input('attribute_name.*') as $key => $val)
               {
                   print_r($key);
                   print_r($val);
               }
```

Comment: because the input is named `attribute_name` not `attribute_name.*`  ... `attribute_name` is the array itself that you want to iterate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @lagbox you have to use attribute_names instead of attribute_names.*

```
foreach($this->request('attribute_names') as $key => $value) {
    print_r($key);
}
```

As the attribute_names itself an array while defining it under input box you just have to use it under foreach and you will easily get the key of each input boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The short example of dynamic input  :

```
<form action="" method="post">   
  <input type="text" name="attribute_name[]" value="One">
  <input type="text" name="attribute_name[]" value="Two">
  <input type="text" name="attribute_name[]" value="Three">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in your controller you will be able to get all `attribute_name` values like this :

```
$attribute_name = $request->attribute_name; // give you an array with values
```

You can get all data by a `foreach` loop :

```
foreach($request->attribute_name as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key : " . $key . ", Value : ". $value . "<br>";
}
```

Output :

`Key : 1, Value : One` 
`Key : 2, Value : Two` 
`Key : 3, Value : Three`

Answer (score -1):

You should use name 'attribute_names' to get array not 'attribute_name.*' try the following code

```
$requestData = $request->input('attribute_names');
foreach($requestData as $key => $val)
 {
      print_r($key);
      print_r($val);
  }
```